# Is the "reverse" of the $33$ rd Fermat number composite?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, prime-factorization, big-numbers, fermat-numbers

If we write down the digits of the $33$ rd Fermat number $$F_{33}=2^{2^{33}}+1$$ in base $10$ in reverse order , the resulting number should , considering its magnitude , be composite.

> But can we search for a prime factor WITHOUT actually calculating $F_{33}$ ? $F_{33}$ begins with a $9$ , so there is no obvious prime factor of the reversed number. Can I , for example , determine whether the reverse of $F_{33}$ is divisible by $7$ ?

Comment: Why do you wish to avoid using a computer to programmatically compute the reverse digits of $~F_{33}?~$ Assuming that the reversal is composite, it is almost certainly divisible by some prime less that $~100,000.~$  Java has the BigInteger class, and (presumably) programming languages like C or Python have similar facilities, so confining all calculations to integers (i.e. avoiding floating point calculations) is straightforward.

Comment: @user2661923 I am not aware of a program with that I can handle such monster numbers with the memory of my computer. If you know such a program and have such a computer , you can do the calculations. Note that we need not only the number itself , we must also actively create the reverse. My memory limit does not even allow to make this with numbers of around $100$ million digits.

Comment: The probability that there is no prime factor below $10^5$ is about $18$% (We already know that $2,3,5$ cannot be a prime factor) , so the "risk" that the smallest prime factor exceeds $10^5$ is not so small.

Comment: Very interesting points, in both of your comments.  Re your first comment, it was my carelessness for not examining $~F_{33}~$ closely enough.  I assumed that $~F_{33} < 10^{10000},~$ but now I see that $\displaystyle ~F_{33} > 10^{\left(2^{31}\right)} > 10^{\left(10^9\right)}.~$ So, $~F_{33}~$ has more than 1 billion digits, which no standard home PC can handle.

Comment: @user2661923 Exactly.